# python pandas: try to read txt file but showed NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a txt file and I want to read it with pandas,

[image]

and I wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
TC=pd.read_csv('D885_Ch10_ZC.csv',error_bad_lines=False,encoding='gbk')
df=pd.DataFrame(TC,columns=['t[s]','digits[]','Ch10_zc[V]'])
print(df)
```

and I found the data was replace by NaN which I don't know why.

[image]

What goes wrong?

---

thx @jezrael 's answer. It works after I deleted all the useless information on the top. Is there anyway to do this without editing the original file?

Comment: Please post your actual input and output data as text, not as images. No one wants to type all of that from the image.

Comment: yes thanks for your kind remind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `sep` parameter, because default is `sep=','`.

if `tab`:

```
names=['t[s]','digits[]','Ch10_zc[V]']
df=pd.read_csv('D885_Ch10_ZC.csv', 
               sep='\t', 
               error_bad_lines=False,
               encoding='gbk', 
               names=names,
               skiprows=1 )
```

if whitespaces:

```
names=['t[s]','digits[]','Ch10_zc[V]']
df=pd.read_csv('D885_Ch10_ZC.csv', 
               sep='\s+',
               encoding='gbk', 
               error_bad_lines=False,
               names=names,
               skiprows=1)
```

---

```
names=['t[s]','digits[]','Ch10_zc[V]']
df=pd.read_csv('D885_Ch10_ZC.csv', 
               delim_whitespace=True,
               encoding='gbk',
               error_bad_lines=False,
               names=names,
               skiprows=1)
```

and if 2 or more whitespaces:

```
names=['t[s]','digits[]','Ch10_zc[V]']
df=pd.read_csv('D885_Ch10_ZC.csv', 
               sep=r'\s{2,}', 
               engine='python', 
               encoding='gbk', 
               names=names,
               skiprows=1 )
```

EDIT:

Need change skiprows to `10`:

```
names=['t[s]','digits[]','Ch10_zc[V]']
df=pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), 
               delim_whitespace=True,
               encoding='gbk', 
               names=names,
               skiprows=10)
```

Comment: thx it works after I deleted all the useless information on the top.